# Get the database name in MySQL without using SELECT DATABASE()

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do an SQL Injection attack, (This is for an assignment, so I'm not doing anything illegal) and I need to see what the current database name is. However, I'm limited to 15 characters for the input, which is 13 when you factor in escaping the string and commenting out the remainder. SELECT DATABASE() is too long because of this, so is there a way to return the database name in 13 characters or less?

Comment: can you increase the 15 char limit?

Comment: How would I do that? Isn't the  character limit evaluated server side?

Comment: you could try to send an input longer then 15 chars and test if it works. for more help i would need more information

Answer (score 2):

You can use SCHEMA() as it's a synonym for DATABASE(). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_schema

Comment: That's still above the character limit

Answer (score 1):

Use `STATUS`.  It gives you several status variables including the name of the database you are connected to.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-status.html

Comment: `SHOW STATUS` does not include that information. You might be thinking of the [mysql client builtin command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html) `status` which includes the current database. But client builtin commands are not executed by the server, so they're not vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: No... the OP will not be able to run `status` using SQL injection. It's a client builtin command. One cannot execute client commands using SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The command `SHOW TABLES` is only 11 characters, and the heading of the result set reveals the current database.

Here's an example:

```
mysql> use test;
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| ...            |
+----------------+
```